# How to call the decorators with yield?

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to setup a SSH connectivity in my script. The SSH function takes care of start connection and close connection. Then several functions are used to inject the SSH function for getting some data.

if i use; this below code works ok

```
def ssh(self):
    print('entering ...')
    self.ssh = SSHClient()
    self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    self.ssh.connect('localhst:8080')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(
    'ls -al && pwd && cd /TivoData/Log/webservices/mind2-18030.dir/ && ls -al')
    stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    lines = stdout.readlines()
    for line in lines:
       print(line)
    yield self.ssh
    print('closing ...')
    self.ssh.close()

class SSHConnect:

    @pytest.yield_fixture
    def ssh(self, host):
        print('entering ...')
        self.ssh = SSHClient()
        self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        self.ssh.connect(host)
        yield self.ssh
        print('closing ...')
        self.ssh.close()


    def test_execute(self, ssh('localhost:8080'), command):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(
            'ls -al && pwd && cd /home/bharath/ && ls -al')
        stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
        lines = stdout.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
        stdin.close()

obj = SSHConnect()
obj.test_execute()
```

1. How to use ssh(anyhostofwish) and use it in test_execute ?
2. obj.test_execute() is not working, what to use ?
3. self.ssh.exec_command('ls -al && pwd && cd /home/bharath/ && ls -al') is throwing error

Answer (score 0):

You should use Context Manager for SSH connection instead of decorator. A Context Manager can guarantees to close the SSH connection in every case after your operations. 
Here is an good example for SSH Context Manager implementation : https://packetpushers.net/using-python-context-managers/